# i have problem when i calculate zero faces by tool box addon

Tags: add-on, 3d-printing

I modeled a dragon and I am preparing it now to be printable :[image: The problem]

It selects nearly all the mesh, I do "merge by distance" is there a problem or what.
This is the method of how I applied the scale and size of the model in cm. This is the photo of that:[image]

This is the blender file before applying the scale :[blend. file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fFGGZkMOQqNqGTaRBdebSmhPBexfjiNL/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: How big is the model and have you applied the scale to the object? Faces smaller than a certain threshold can also be classified as zero faces. What happens if you delete them?

Comment: I updated the question above and put the method of applying the scale and size in cm.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no manual for the [3D Print Toolbox](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/3d_print_toolbox.html) yet, I had to consult the source script to find out how they check for the zero faces. The default cube was used for testing.

The script looks for faces that have an area less than the given threshold. When you use Blender with the default metric settings then 1 Blender unit is 1 meter. And the face areas are also calculated in square meters (m²). The threshold is the value of the *Degenerated* setting. The default value is `0.00010` and it's also measured in m².

Because 0.0001 m² is 1 cm² (=1 cm x 1 cm) the script actually checks for faces that have an area less than 1 cm². And since your model is 13 cm tall when the scale is applied, this is a pretty big value for testing and results in a lot of reported faces.

In the end, you probably just need to lower the threshold and adjust it to match the 3D printer's resolution in m².

Comment: where I can find the 3d printer's resolution and is there another name for it.

Comment: I solved it by applying scale to model by "scale to deltas".